# Missing { and } inserted. Can't find mismatch

Tags: amsmath, missing, gather

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
    \omega_{\max} = \left(\left(\frac{9\pi^5\sigma h_{0\mathrm{Re}}}{8h^2\rho^2Q^2_\bar\varepsilon}\right)(2\ln(\chi)-3)^2\right)^\frac{1}{3}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

I'm getting:

> Missing { inserted.
>
> to be read again
>
> \gdef
>
> l.8\end{gather}

and

> Missing } inserted.
>
> inserted text
>
> }
>
> l.8\end{gather}

I simply can't find the mismatch.

Comment: Note that it is also a coincidence if `^\frac{1}{3}`, again use braces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to encase the subscript term `_\bar\varepsilon` in a pair of curly braces:

```
_{\bar\varepsilon}
```

or, even more cleanly,

```
_{\bar{\varepsilon}}}
```

This is maybe a reminder of sorts that it never hurts -- and frequently very much helps! -- to help TeX out by providing the appropriate `{` and `}` grouping symbols.

A full working example -- note the removal of two pairs of parentheses which don't add much except clutter.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \omega_{\max} = \left[
    \frac{9\pi^5\sigma h_{0\mathrm{Re}}}{%
          8h^2 \rho^2 Q^2_{\bar{\varepsilon}}}
    (2\ln\chi-3)^2\right]^{1/3}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In my opinion, the parentheses around the big fraction are redundant and should be removed.

Comment: @egreg - Good point! I had already removed another set of parentheses and didn't pay enough attention to the bigger (pun intended) issue.

Comment: Yes they are redundant. But if I erase them, the second term is transfered into the denominator for whatever reason (there probably is a reason and I'm too stupid to find it, but...)

Comment: @trumfnator - What do you mean by "the second term"? `(2\ln\chi-3)^2`, maybe? If it's moved to the denominator, then you've most likely got a misplaced `}` curly brace somewhere.

Comment: Probably! But with your solution it's gone anyway, so thanks!